# Android - how to get android.R.anim.slide_in_right

Tags: android, animation

I'm playing about with animations with android. The animations android.R.anim.slide_in_left and android.R.anim.slide_out_right are provided. I'm looking for a way to get the opposite animations i.e:

`android.R.anim.slide_in_right and android.R.anim.slide_out_left`

or how I can specify these myself.

Comment: +1 How can I use the default slide_in_left and slide_out_right function?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Here are [`slide_in_right`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/res/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml) and [`slide_out_left`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/core/res/res/anim/slide_out_left.xml) from the Android open source project.

Comment: @AdilHussain: The definitions are also available in your SDK installation.

Comment: Thanks.  Even though I have 4.3, these animations are missing.  Any ideas why ?

Comment: @deepwinter: I am uncertain as to what you mean by "missing" (cannot reference in a resource? cannot reference in Java? runtime crash? something else?). I also am uncertain what you mean by "I have 4.3" (your build target is 4.3? you are running on 4.3? something else?). You might consider opening your own StackOverflow question with complete details of your environment, test, and symptoms.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have the same issue as deepwinter. I'm building my app using Android 4.2.2 SDK. From android.jar, in android.R, I see only anim.slide_in_left and anim.slide_out_right. There is no slide_in_right or slide_out_left. So in code, I cannot use android.R.anim.slide_out_left as it gives me a compilation error.

Comment: @zzheng: I never said that `android.R.anim.slide_out_left` would work. I did point out a definition of a `slide_out_left` animation resource. You are welcome to copy it or implement your own. Note that this answer was from over four years ago, and so the resource may have changed from the version I link to in the answer.

Comment: I know this is an old reply, but I found the source files in `android-sdks\platforms\android-19\data\res\anim` -- copied into project and they worked.  No idea why they are not auto-detected.

Comment: I think now they're called `slide_left_in` etc instead of `slide_in_left` etc

Comment: Explanation as to why they don't work here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923422/missing-slide-in-right-and-slide-out-left-animations-in-android/75881117#75881117

Answer (score 8):

```
android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `slide_in_right` and `slide_out_left` exist in Android 2.1 and above.