# Need help for android activity transition right to left

Tags: android

I used these below codes for right to left transition.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

and these below codes for left to right

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>`
```

it works fine with this `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.rtol, R.anim.ltor);`

BUT, it shows a black screen when doing transition and not smooth. 
Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: check this link for commonsware's answer on the existing animations in android open source project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274657/android-how-to-get-android-r-anim-slide-in-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried android default `Transitions` that are already available in android.

For example

```
@android:anim/slide_in_left
```

and

```
@android:anim/slide_out_right
```